# Angular2 directive subscribed to an Observable cannot refresh the view

Tags: angular

I have a directive (@Directive) that is subscribed to an observable. When an event is emitted the directive modifies the style (CSS) of the decorated view.

This does not work, i.e. the CSS is not modified although my code is called. If I modify the decorated component's CSS in the directive's constructor it works.

By the way I have tried to subscribe to the observable in the directive's constructor and in the ngOnInit() but without success.

This is the directive code:

```
@Directive({
   providers: [FooService],
   selector: '[foo]',
})
export class FooDirective {

constructor(private _renderer: Renderer, private _el: ElementRef, private _fooService: FooService) {

     // modify the CSS style when the directive is initialized
     this._renderer.setElementStyle(this._el, 'color', 'yellow'); // this works

     _fooService.subscribe(myevent => {
         // modify the CSS style on an event
         this._renderer.setElementStyle(this._el, 'color', 'yellow'); // this does not work (although it is called)
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: When you add `console.log(myevent);` to  `subscribe()`, does it write to the console?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yes it writes (see my comment: "although it is called")

Comment: Can you try if the `setElementStyle` works from a click handler? I haven't used `Renderer` myself. Maybe it only works in the  constructor.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer The problem was not the usage of the Renderer. Please check the answer added in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working sample: https://plnkr.co/edit/ELWlaG8Zkdq4BDvo4al4?p=preview. Your code seems to be correct...

I guess that the service instance isn't shared by the element that triggers the event and the directive that subscribes it. Do you define the service provider at the `bootstrap` level?

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {TestService} from './service';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ TestService ]);
```

Is the callback defined in the `subscribe` method called when the event is fired?

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER**

I noticed (thanks @Thierry for your sample) that I have 'providers: [FooService],' which makes the directive to not use the singleton FooService registered in the bootstrap (as you mention). The solution was to remove the FooService from the providers.